# How to derive NW standard errors for impulse responses from lpirfs package in R or calculate them?

Tags: r, standard-error, robust-standard-error, impulse-response

In my thesis, I have to derive impulse responses with IV using 2sls. I use the package in R "lpirfs" and specifically the lp_lin_iv function. My results have F stat and P-value. But I want the NW standard errors that this function computes in the background. I have not so much experience with R so I can not understand from GitHub how can I do this.
The link is https://github.com/AdaemmerP/lpirfs/blob/master/R/lp_nl_iv.R

Thank you.

Comment: [This](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/795/124848) collection of resources for support for R packages may offer some further options for finding help as this seems like more of a software/implementation question than a statistics question.

Comment: I wrote to the author of the package and this is the answer : (results_lin_iv of irf_lin_up - results_lin_iv of irf_lin_mean)/confint .